# Javascript inside a while loop. Is this acceptable practice?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on improving the usability of the backend of my website, moving many functions that required page reloads into AJAX controlled popups.
One issue I have come across follows.
I have two images for a product, clicking 'More Info' I want to load the information abut that specific image into the popup. To achieve this, each 'More Info' button needs to be uniquely identified, so I set the classes on the buttons to be like this

```
<img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_info.gif" border="0" alt="Image Info" title=" Image Info " class="layout-info-orange-shirt-min">
```

and

```
<img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_info.gif" border="0" alt="Image Info" title=" Image Info " class="layout-info-orange-shirt-min_01">
```

where orange-shirt-min and orange-shirt-min_01 are the contents of the variable

```
$tmp_image_name
```

My script is

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   // Variable to hold original content
   var original_content = '';      
   $(".layout-info-<?php echo $tmp_image_name; ?>").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
           url: 'product_image_ajax.php?action=layout_info',
           data: {
            products_filter: '<?php echo $products_filter; ?>',
           products_name: '<?php echo $pInfo->products_name; ?>',
           preview_image: '<?php echo '../'.$preview_image; ?>',
            imgName: '<?php echo $tmp_image_name; ?>',
            imgExt: '<?php echo $products_image_extension; ?>'
            }
       })
       .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
       var elem = $('.tooltipster-content');
       var original_content_qty = elem.html();
       elem.fadeOut('slow', function() {
           elem.html(data).fadeIn('slow');
           $("#defaultContent").addClass("hidden");
       });
       })
       .fail(function(){
           alert('Ajax Submit for Layout Info Failed ...');
       });
   });
});
```

The problem I ran into was that clicking the first image with the class name of layout-info-orange-shirt-min resulted in a full page reload without AJAX.
I eventually figured out that because my script is outside the while loop, $tmp_image_name only ever contained the name of the last image from the php loop.
Moving the script inside the loop makes it function as I wanted. Whilst it works, I don't want to code something that is classed as bad practice.

So the question is, in these circumstances is it acceptable to have the javascript inside the php loop, or should I get a count of the number of images from the loop, and then pass that down to the script outside of the loop?

If I did need to pass a value like $i from php, how could that be incorporated into

```
$(".layout-info-<?php echo $tmp_image_name; ?>").click(function(e){
```

so that the script knew which Info button had been clicked?

Comment: totally wrong, you can get all elements by the same class, or give different ID's in code behind, many ways to solve this issue...

Comment: @Proxytype I can't get the results by using the same class. If I have three images for a product and each 'More Info' button has the same class, then how is the script supposed to know which button out of three was clicked, and thus, what values to apply to the variables that are passed to the code in the action switch?
The whole point of appending the image name to the button class was so that each was unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic breakdown of handling multiple events in one handler can be done in multiple ways, but here is one way which works fairly easily.

First, adjust your img buttons to have a piece of data in an attribute like so:

```
<img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_info.gif" 
 border="0" alt="Image Info" title=" Image Info" 
 class="layout-info" data-imgname="orange-shirt-min">

<img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_info.gif" 
 border="0" alt="Image Info" title=" Image Info" 
 class="layout-info" data-imgname="orange-shirt-min_01">
```

The key change here is to have a common class for all images (which ties to the event handler). Now, you only need one javascript block to handle them all. This is the base framework:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $(".layout-info").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
           url: 'product_image_ajax.php?action=layout_info',
           data: {
             ...
             imgName: $(this).data('imgname'), // dynamic
             products_filter: <?php echo json_encode($products_filter);?>, // static
             ...
           }
       })...
   });
});
```

From this example, you can extrapolate any extra data args you need per 'info', and also set some static args that work for all. However this should give you an idea how this one event handler can handle the click of multiple info buttons.

The magic comes from utilizing `$(this)` which refers to the button that was clicked, along with it, any attributes and object methods.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Learned something new, which is always a good thing